# Get rid of additional text in footer

Tags: magento, text

I can't seem to figure out out to get rid of the additional text in Magento 1.9 next to the subscribe button. Pic is attached. It's our website but don't know how it got there. Please help.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVSOC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In magento Newsletter block called in this phtml file.
Path of file is :

```
app\design\frontend\[YOUR THEME]\template\newsletter\subscribe.phtml
```

In that file, the code for button is this,

```
<div class="actions">
      <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Subscribe')) ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?></span></span></button>
</div>
```

You can put your code after this, so it will appear there.

Comment: Hi Dhiren. Thank you for answering but I'm not trying to add text. I'm trying to get rid of it. Can you see the "Sample" I included in my initial question please.

Comment: But it is showing it on the home page next to the subscribe button. Not on the subscribe button. I went to that file and the website address that is showing is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Turn ON the developers options from the admin side and referesh your page.. From there you will know from which phtml this content is loaded. go to that phtml and remove the code.  If you want to remove a phtml file then you can do this from local.xml.